# issue with $.ParseJSON which converts json string to null

Tags: jquery, json, spring, parsing

I am using spring mvc in which i convert the arraylist into json string.  I have one object 1) results.

My output from spring looks like this:

```
{
"data":"[{\"userName\":\"test1\",\"firstName\":\"test\",\"lastName\":\"user\"},        {\"userName\":\"test2\",\"firstName\":\"test1\",\"lastName\":\"user1\"}]",
}
```

I get output as null when i do '**$.parseJSON**' with this output.  When i tried testing only with data object it works fine

Any help would be great.

Comment: @DeathBedMotorcade : Yes, thats what i am expecting for results object.  But the url object seems to be failing.  When i tried parsing only results it works fine as it gives me object, but when i tried parsing url, it gives me **unexpected syntax found h**

Comment: @Aby try escaping the url "http:\/\/google.com\/subdomain ..."

Comment: @dadu :  How can i escape this url in java ?

Comment: String s = "http:\\/\\/google..."

Comment: not manually is there any method i can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue,  I was parsing the outer object, which had object in it instead of string.  So it was failing.  When i parsed $.parseJSON(mainResult.data), it worked fine as the data object contains string in it.